# Constructing tree from symbolic input

Tags: recursion, tree, scheme

I am trying to construct a tree in scheme language , from string input. Following is what i have tried -

```
(define travsal (lambda (tree)
             (cond
               ((null? tree) '())
               (#t (append (travsal (car tree)) (cons (cadr tree)
(travsal (caddr tree))))))))

 (define tree1 '(((() 4 ()) 2 (() 5 ())) 1 ((() 6 ()) 3 (() 7 ()))))

  (display tree1)
  (newline)

  (travsal tree1)
```

As you can see its just iterating the input provided and not doing what actual binary tree should do.
I am struck at the logic as of how to save the tree using nodes and child from symbolic input like - "(((() 4 ()) 2 (() 5 ())) 1 ((() 6 ()) 3 (() 7 ()))))" and then print it out like above function is printing.

Please help out , i was asked this question in an interview and still can't solve it.

Comment: Now they're asking Scheme questions in interviews? fantastic! where is this job, so I can apply to it? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "not doing what actual binary tree should do"? . The traversal code is fine, it's doing an [in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) of the tree. Fixing some formatting issues:

```
(define travsal
  (lambda (tree)
    (cond ((null? tree) '())
          (else (append (travsal (car tree))
                        (cons (cadr tree)
                              (travsal (caddr tree))))))))
```

Now, bear in mind that the tree you provided is binary but *not* sorted:

```
(define tree1 '(((() 4 ()) 2 (() 5 ())) 1 ((() 6 ()) 3 (() 7 ()))))
```

If we draw it, it'll look like this:

```
       1
     /   \
   2       3
  /  \   /   \
4     5 6     7
```

Which, after an in-order traversal will correctly yield this result when using the `travsal` procedure:

```
(travsal tree1)
=> '(4 2 5 1 6 3 7)
```

Comment: If pre order or post order binary tree has to be printed than i again have to write a logic starting from scratch. Instead if i could store the tree first and apply the output logic on it . Or will this be fine what i have ?

Comment: I don't follow you. How do you want to "print" it? is it a traversal, or an actual drawing? . If you want to switch from, say, pre-order to post-order yes, you'd have to write a different procedure (but it's simple, just change the order of the parameters to `append`, adding the root in a list). The tree representation you're using is fine, there's no need to store it elsewhere, you can apply the output logic directly over it.

Comment: Thank you Oscar , That will do.

Comment: Just a quick question - "parsing the text string and build the tree in an internal data-structure" , i got confused at this point as i am not building any kind of binary tree in my code , its just using the input from the user. Will this can be sufficient as per that aspect ?

Comment: @BeingCoder it depends on how you receive the actual input. If it's truly a _string_ then you'll have to evaluate it and convert it into a list of symbols that looks like `tree1`. If the input is _already_ a list of symbols then that's already the data structure we need, a list can be used to represent a tree, as shown above.